# XSLT doubling outputs with variances for toggled HTML view

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-2.0

XSLT 2.0

The ultimate goal for my project is to output a webpage which provides two views of the same medieval document to the user according to two academic standards, between which the user can toggle with a button (see a proof of concept from 18 months and many iterations ago [here](http://admin.exist-db.org:44455/exist/apps/inquipedia/depositions.html?depofile=ms609_0452_esteve_fabri.xml) ).

This requires me to frequently output two HTML segments from a single XSLT template call, differentiated by their  `@class` with value 'inter' or 'diplo'. This is beginning to negatively affect the 'named entities' (people and places) which are subject to multiple templates.

For example, at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBtW one finds that I treat the very first instance of `<persName>`:

```
 <persName nymRef="#Bernard_Cogota_MSP-AU" role="dep">B<supplied reason="expname">ernardus</supplied> Cogata</persName>
```

So that it outputs:

```
 <a href="http://foo.com/person/Bernard_Cogota_MSP-AU" class="inter">Bernardus Cogata</a>
 <span class="diplo">Bernardus Cogata</span>
```

But, if I add this template (seen at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBtW/1):

```
<xsl:template match="tei:supplied">
    <span class="supplied inter"><xsl:apply-templates/></span>
    <span class="supplied diplo">[<xsl:apply-templates/>]</span>
</xsl:template>
```

It outputs the two spans to both the `<persName>` outputs, which will produce incorrect display results from javascript and css:

```
<a href="http://foo.com/person/Bernard_Cogota_MSP-AU" class="inter">B<span class="supplied inter">ernardus</span><span class="supplied diplo">[ernardus]</span> Cogata</a>
<span class="diplo">B<span class="supplied inter">ernardus</span><span class="supplied diplo">[ernardus]</span> Cogata</span>
```

I'm wondering if there is a way within XSLT to output rather:

```
<a href="http://foo.com/person/Bernard_Cogota_MSP-AU" class="inter">B<span class="supplied inter">ernardus</span> Cogata</a>
<span class="diplo">B<span class="supplied diplo">[ernardus]</span> Cogata</span>
```

Should I instead be considering dumping out the document body (currently ) into two separate `<div class="inter">` and `<div class="diplo">`? Possibly using `modes` to then build the separate `<div>`?

The alternate is to set a unique class for each discrete template output and then manage the toggle effect with a large list of classes instead of a whole group. But it strikes me that would be an inelegant solution that outputs more than necessary to the browser.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I have not managed to understand the details of your current XSLT approach but looking the example http://admin.exist-db.org:44455/exist/apps/inquipedia/depositions.html?depofile=ms609_0452_esteve_fabri.xml you linked to and your own suggestion to use 'two separate `<div class="inter">` and `<div class="diplo">`' and then to use separate modes to push the right content to those two `div`s I would say, yes, that seems like the cleaner approach and the cleaner Javascript/CSS `display` toggling than having hundreds of spans that need to be toggled (even if JQuery or modern DOM make that easy).

Comment: @MartinHonnen indeed, it's a deep encoding of textual documents which I only post fragments of here. It's broken into three parts: the Latin, the translation(s), and the footnotes. As you know now (and constructed for me), the footnotes run under one `mode`. If I use two different `modes` to construct two different `divs`, (ie. `mode="inter"` and `mode ="diplo"`)both of which use the same footnotes, will I run into 'conflicting' of modes? That is to say, will the footnote mode be integrated into both of the `div`s?

Comment: I don't see the footnotes in the current example https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBtW, I am not sure where you had them and whether they will be different for the two different divs, if not, depending on the layout and document structure, I would expect them to be put in a section or div outside of those two divs and that way I would not expect any conflict.

Comment: This is the version with footnotes (in fact, two sets of footnotes: app-sources and footnotes-sources) https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwY/1. They should appear equally in each potential <div>.

Comment: After rearranging per <div>, some minor problems coordinating modes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52924340/xslt-2-0-co-ordinating-multiple-modes