# XSLT 2.0 co-ordinating multiple modes

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, tei

XSLT 2.0, stylesheet and data at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2D3/4

I am transforming medieval documents encoded in tei-xml into webpages where the user can toggle between two different views of the documents, as well as see the translation and various footnotes ([eg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918041/xslt-doubling-outputs-with-variances-for-toggled-html-view)). This requires multiple layers of processing to output:

- Two latin versions ('inter' and 'diplo') between which the user can toggle (derived from the same tei markup)
- Translated version with almost no transformations (just paragraph formatting and italics)
- Critical apparatus using footnoting # a, b, c, etc.
- Historical footnotes using footnoting # 1, 2, 3, etc.

I am using `modes` in order to handle the levels of processing, and each mode on its own works fine, but together they are missing outputs.

What should output:

1. `<div class="inter"><p>` with all transformations mode `inter` + `fn-add-marker` 
   [this should contain `<a href>`, superscript letters and numbers in text]
2. `<div  class="diplo"><p>` with all transformations mode `diplo` + `fn-add-marker` 
   [this should contain [text] , line numbers, superscript letters and numbers in text]
3. `<div><p>` with translations
4. `<div>` with critical apparatus
5. `<div>` with footnotes

The XSLTfiddle output is:

1. URL and superscript letters ok! **missing superscript numbers** (mode `fn-add-marker`)
2. Superscript letters ok! Line # and [text] ok **except where inside `<persName>` or `<placeName>`** (ie.`<xsl:template match="tei:lb">` `<xsl:template match="tei:supplied">`) and **missing superscript numbers** (mode `fn-add-marker`)
3. ok!
4. ok!
5. ok!

With respect to #2, the missing line # and [text] appear to be a result of the templates that treat `<persName>` and `<placeName>` not handing off to other templates? (templates at lines 173-218)

All templates concerning mode `fn-add-marker` are at lines 41-77.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically in XSLT 2, once you work with named modes, you need to make sure in a template belonging to a certain mode, having e.g. `mode="foo"`, that you use e.g. `mode="foo"` or more general `mode="#current"` on any `xsl:apply-templates` inside to ensure processing continues in that mode. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-apply-templates for details.

At https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiK7 I have tried XSLT to fix your stylesheet and then at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2D3/5 you can see the result of applying the fixed stylesheet. Not sure whether that programmatic approach is the right tool but it might help to demonstrate the suggested use mode `mode` on `xsl:apply-templates`.

Then I think you need to make sure you process the added markers in the two new modes:

```
<!-- adds fn numbers -->
<xsl:template match="tei:date[@type='deposition_date']" mode="inter dilpo">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="number"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tei:note[@type='public'] | tei:fn-marker" mode="inter diplo">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="number"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tei:date[@type='deposition_date'] |  tei:note[@type='public'] | tei:fn-marker" mode="number">
    <sup>
       <xsl:number count="tei:date[@type='deposition_date'] |  tei:note[@type='public'] | tei:fn-marker" format="1" level="any"/>
    </sup>
</xsl:template>
<!-- end of footnote transformations -->
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2D3/6 lines 51 to 66.

Comment: Right, thanks. So, what I don't see is how to get the mode `fn-add-marker` to  then output - at what point does it become 'current'. It's as though the processor doesn't see it and I haven't been able to find the entry point to call it..as it needs to perform the transformation twice (for 'inter' and 'diplo' outputs).

Comment: See the edit to the answer, if I am not lost then you don't need to change that `fn-add-marker` mode, instead you need to make sure the code for converting markers and notes to numbers is now applied in the two modes `inter` and `diplo` you introduced.

Comment: Ah, I had the logic inverted (and no, you are not lost). I also didn't know one could put two modes in `mode`. This is fantastic, and I learned a lot again. Thanks.